# Rewriting Markov process

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

Let $X$ be a Markov proces with state space $(E,\mathcal{E})$with initial distribution $\nu$ and transition function $P_{t}$, so $$E_{\nu}(f(X_{t+s})\mid\mathcal{F}_{s})=P_{t}f(X_{s})$$
Suppose that $(E',\mathcal{E}')$ is a measurable space and let $\phi:E\rightarrow E'$ be measurable and onto. 
Let $Q_{t}$ be a collection of kernels such that $$P_{t}(f\circ\phi)=(Q_{t}f)\circ\phi$$

I would now like to prove that $\phi(X)$, is a Markov process with respect to the state space $(E',\mathcal{E}')$, initial measure $\nu'$, where $\nu'(B')=\nu(\phi^{-1}(B'))$ and transition function $Q_{t}$.

So basically I would like to prove that $$E_{\nu'}(f(\phi(X_{t+s}))\mid\mathcal{F}_{s})=Q_{t}f(\phi(X_{s}))$$
Here is my try as $\phi$ is onto and f is assumed to be a bounded function 
$$E_{\nu'}(f(\phi(X_{t+s}))\mid\mathcal{F}_{s})=E_{\nu}(\phi^{-1}(f(\phi(X_{t+s})))\mid\mathcal{F}_{s})$$
$$=P_{t}\phi^{-1}(f(\phi(X_{s})))=(Q_{t}\phi^{-1})(f(\phi(X_{s})))$$

From this point on I do not know how to proceed.
Could anyone help me further?

Answer (score 1):

> So basically I would like to prove that $$E_{\nu'}(f(X_{t+s})\mid\mathcal{F}_{s})=Q_{t}f(X_{s})$$

No, basically you would like to prove that, if $Y_t=\phi(X_t)$ and $\mathcal{F}^Y_t=\sigma(Y_s;s\leqslant t)$ for every $t$, then
$$
E_{\nu'}(f(Y_{t+s})\mid\mathcal{F}^Y_{s})=Q_{t}f(Y_{s}),
$$
not what you wrote. You could then show that this is equivalent to
$$
E_{\nu}(f(\phi(X_{t+s}))\mid\mathcal{F}_{s})=Q_{t}f(\phi(X_{s})),
$$
the definition of $\nu'$ allowing you to replace $\nu'$ by $\nu$, and the hypothesis that $\phi$ is onto allowing you to replace each $\mathcal{F}^Y_{s}$ by $\mathcal{F}_{s}$. You might want to proceed from there.

Comment: Yeah sorry my bad.. My problem is getting rid of the $\phi^{-1}$

Comment: ?? The point is there is basically no $\phi^{-1}$ to get rid of.

Comment: So you can basically replace $\nu'$ by $\nu$ without using that $\nu'=\nu\phi^{-1}$?

Comment: ??? What can I say?

Comment: @user70267 Note that $\mathbb{E}_{\mu}$ is only a notation, meaning that you are taking the (conditional) expectation wrt to a measure such that the distribution of the given process at time $t=0$ is equal to $\mu$. So $\mathbb{E}_{\nu'}(g(Y_t) \mid \mathcal{F}_s^Y)$ because $\mathbb{P}[Y_0 \in B] = \mathbb{P}[X_0 \in \varphi^{-1}(B)] = \nu'(B)$ whereas you have $\mathbb{E}_{\nu}(g(X_t) \mid \mathcal{F}_s)$ since $\mathbb{P}[X_0 \in B] = \nu(B)$.

Comment: @saz Thanks, this explanation escaped me.

Comment: Thank you, it is clear to me now

Comment: Does anything change if I want to show that $Y$ is Markov with respect to $\mathcal{F}_{t}$?

Comment: Do you see a difference between $\mathcal F^X_t$ and $\mathcal F^Y_t$ if $\phi$ is onto?

Comment: I've been following thing topic, since I believe the original poster and myself are following the same subject. What I'm wondering, is it true that $f \circ \Phi$ is also bounded (and measurable)?

Comment: Ah, since $f$ is bounded, then the composition is bounded as well. Then you're almost done!

Comment: @BallzofFury Is there still a question in your comments?

Comment: No, I managed to figure it out. I thought I'd try and give the OP some help.

Comment: Can you define the measure $P_\nu$ with respect you do the integration?

Comment: @peer This is the notation used in the question and in every textbook on the subject: $P_\nu$ is the probability measure such that the distribution of $X_0$ is $\nu$. If you like symbols, $$(X_0)_*(P_\nu)=\nu$$

Comment: So $P_\nu$ is a measure on the path space which depends on the markov process X?

Comment: @peer $P_\nu$ is a probability measure on the probability space $\Omega$ on which every $X_t$ is defined. Just like $P$.

Comment: @peer Two points. First, if the formula in your comment was correct, the process $(X_t)$ would be independent, which is obviously not the case for a general Markov process. Second, if you have a mathematical question, reviving three years old posts by posting comments is not the way to proceed. You should instead post a separate question, which would avoid parasiting other posts and would allow you to explain more clearly what it is you are after, thus avoiding frustration on all sides involved.

Comment: @peer I now see your comments here are a kind of offshoot of [this question of yours](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1928628/), that you did not even mention... Politeness aside, should we understand that the answer you received there (and accepted) failed to solve your queries?